# Multiple Queries Need Combines Result phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin

In the SQL window of phpMyAdmin is shows a delimiter of  ; between queries. Its runnng all the queries I have in it just only showing results of the last one. How do I get it to combine the results to one?

```
SELECT  field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6 
FROM table WHERE field2 = "AA" AND field3 LIKE '%BBB%';
SELECT  field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6 
FROM table WHERE field2 = "AA" AND field3 LIKE '%CCC%';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `UNION`?

```
SELECT  field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6 
FROM table WHERE field2 = "AA" AND field3 LIKE '%BBB%'
UNION
SELECT  field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6 
FROM table WHERE field2 = "AA" AND field3 LIKE '%CCC%';
```

**Update**

A simplification on your query:

```
SELECT  field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6 
FROM table WHERE field2 = "AA" AND (field3 LIKE '%BBB%' OR field3 LIKE '%CCC%')
```